# Jenkinsfile - a way to skip the whole pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I use the [declarative syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) for developing the (**multibranch**) pipeline script and I'm looking for a way to **skip the whole pipeline based on some condition**, without having to modify the `when` on every single stage.

Current use case: I'm setting up a `cron` to trigger builds at night, but I only want let's say the branches `release/v1` and `develop` to go through the pipeline at night, not the dozen of other branches.

```
triggers {
  cron('H 21 * * 1-5')
}

// SKIP PIPELINE if triggered by timer AND branch not 'release/v1' OR 'develop'

stages {
  stage('build') {
    when { ... }
  }
  stage('UT') {
    when { ... }
  }
etc...
}
```

any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it safe to assume this is a multi-branch pipeline, since otherwise this would not be an issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can nest stages, if you have the pipeline-definition-plugin 1.3 or later ([changelog](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-model-definition)).

Using that, you can nest your whole job in a parent stage, and use a when directive on the parent stage. All child stages will be skipped if the parent stage is skipped. Here is an example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Parent') {
            when {
                //...
            }
            stages {
                stage('build') {
                    steps {
                        //..
                    }
                }
                stage('UT') {
                    steps {
                        //...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It did work after I upgraded the Jenkins. Very helpful! Saved me. Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW., Jenkins docs is out of date, at least for this point. I didn't find any words about the `nested stages` in their docs.

Comment: @Bruce the official announcement from 2018 is here: https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2018/07/02/whats-new-declarative-piepline-13x-sequential-stages/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [SCM Skip](https://plugins.jenkins.io/scmskip/) plugin. Then use it in the pipeline like so:

```
scmSkip(deleteBuild: true, skipPattern:'.*#skip-ci.*')
```

This also enables to delete the build and also use a regex expression easily. The problem is, it aborts the next builds, and then ignores them for the relevant PR if you're connected with GitHub organization.